# How to customize dired-compress-files-alist?

Tags: emacs, compression, hook, archive, dired

The original value of `dired-compress-files-alist` is:

```lisp
    (("\\.tar\\.gz\\'" . "tar -cf - %i | gzip -c9 > %o") ("\\.tar\\.bz2\\'" . "tar -cf - %i | bzip2 -c9 > %o") ("\\.tar\\.xz\\'" . "tar -cf - %i | xz -c9 > %o") ("\\.tar\\.zst\\'" . "tar -cf - %i | zstd -19 -o %o") ("\\.zip\\'" . "zip %o -r --filesync %i"))
```

I'd like to add command for `.tgz` files, so I add a line in `.emacs`:

```lisp
    (add-hook 'dired-mode
              '(lambda ()
                 (setq dired-compress-files-alist
                       (cons '("\\.tgz\\'" . "tar -cf - %i | gzip -c9 > %o") dired-compress-files-alist))))
```

When Emacs starts, it reports error `variable dired-compress-files-alist is not found`. I found only when I run command `dired-do-compress-to', this variable will appear. So how to set this variable?

Comment: What functionality are you trying to add to emacs?

Answer (score 2):

Just require standard library `dired-aux` in your init file at the outset (at least before you use Dired). That library defines variable `dired-compress-files-alist`.

```lisp
(require 'dired-aux)
```

---

(Oh, and don't quote lambdas: just use `(lambda...)`, not `'(lambda...)`.)

---

(You can also use `add-to-list` or `push` instead of `setq` with `cons` etc., but that's just a question of style.)

Comment: Thanks.  These two lines work:
(require 'dired-aux)
(add-to-list 'dired-compress-files-alist '("\\.tgz\\'" . "tar -cf - %i | gzip -c9 > %o"))